# Which is the best way to create CSV file with huge data say(5 million records)?

Tags: c#, .net, ssis, windows-services, bcp

My take is Windows service with `ADO.NET`. Question is load on the server if simultaneous requests??

How about calling `SSIS` through `Windows-Service`??

I may need to include some `.net` libraries for formatting `ex:CSVHelper`

Answer (score 0):

Hm? The question is tagged with bcp, which should be a good solution. For example:

```
bcp myDatabase.myTable out myFile.csv -S localhost\SqlSrv2008 -T -w
```

[This post](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/working-with-the-bcp-command-line-utility/) has a clear explanation of the options. Automate with c# and [Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx) as needed?